# Best hash algorithm for a data index (ie, crc)

Tags: php, file, hash

Basically, I'm keeping track of file modifications, in something like:

```
array (
    'crc-of-file' => 'latest-file-contents'
)
```

This is because I'm working on the file contents of different files at runtime at the same time.

So, the question is, what hashing algorithm should I use over the file contents (as a string, since the file is being loaded anyway)?

Collision prevention is crucial, as well as performance. I don't see any security implications in this so far.

**Edit:** Another thing I could have used instead of hashing contents is the file modification timestamp, but I wasn't sure how reliable it is. On the other hand, I think it's faster to monitor the said stamp than hashing the file each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CRC it's not a hashing algorithm, a checksum algorithm so your chances of collision will be quite high.

`md5` is quite fast and the collision risk is rather minimal for your kind of application / volume. If you are buffering the file, you may also want to look at [incremental hashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-final.php) using the `hash` extension.

A bit more complex, but also worth looking at (if you have it) is the [`Inotify` extension](http://php.net/manual/en/function.inotify-init.php).

Comment: CRC is a considered as a type of hashing function, see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions

Comment: Inotify cannot work in my case. After some thought, I think I'm going the "modification time" route when possible, and remove the feature altogether when not.